# Querying a normalised table

Tags: sql

I have the following table in my database:

```
KEY         FIELDID CONTENT
TEST0002338 26      rcTRI150003
TEST0002338 25      COOKIE
TEST0002338 24      w008760
TEST0002339 26      rcTRI150003
TEST0002339 25      COOKIE
TEST0002339 24      w008761
TEST0002340 26      rcTRI150003
TEST0002340 25      COOKIE
TEST0002340 24      w008762
TEST0002341 26      rcTRI150003
TEST0002341 25      COOKIE
TEST0002341 24      w008763
TEST0002342 26      rcTRI150003
TEST0002342 25      COOKIE
TEST0002342 24      w008764
TEST0002343 26      rcTRI150003
TEST0002343 25      COOKIE
TEST0002343 24      w008765
```

Now I'm trying to write a query to retrieve the `KEY` if I know three pieces of `CONTENT` and their corresponding `FIELDID`, like this (should return `TEST0002338`):

```
SELECT [KEY]
  FROM [ENTRYFLD]
 WHERE ((("FIELDID"='24') AND ("CONTENT"='w008760')) AND 
       (("FIELDID"='25') AND ("CONTENT"='COOKIE'))) AND 
       (("FIELDID"='26') AND ("CONTENT"='rcTRI150003'))
```

I also tried some other combinations with `OR`, but that didn't work either. What is the correct way to do this (preferably only using very simple commands like `AND` and `OR`, because I don't write the SQL directly but am using a custom wrapper)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't have `JOIN` available in my custom wrapper, unfortunately.

Comment: @BioGeek is it allowed to use `EXISTS` ?

Comment: the obvious thing to do is, of course, to fix the wrapper. don't do ugly hacks.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that is indeed the best long term solution, agreed.

Comment: Why not specify requirements (like no join), in the question - instead of here in the comments...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, joins are convenient, but it can be solved even without joins!

Comment: You might want to add a tag for the specific database you're using; from the syntax I guess it's MS SQL but can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now updated, didn't understand question completely... select possible keys, check if there are at least 3 rows with that key!

```
select "KEY" from
(SELECT DISTINCT "KEY", "FIELDID", "CONTENT"
 FROM "ENTRYFLD"
 WHERE ("FIELDID"='24' AND "CONTENT"='w008760') OR
       ("FIELDID"='25' AND "CONTENT"='COOKIE')  OR 
       ("FIELDID"='26' AND "CONTENT"='rcTRI150003')
)
group by "KEY"
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Updated version, even more simplified:

```
select "KEY" from
FROM "ENTRYFLD"
WHERE ("FIELDID"='24' AND "CONTENT"='w008760') OR
      ("FIELDID"='25' AND "CONTENT"='COOKIE')  OR 
      ("FIELDID"='26' AND "CONTENT"='rcTRI150003')
group by "KEY"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "FIELDID") >= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use self-joins:

```
SELECT t1."KEY"
  FROM ENTRYFLD t1
  JOIN ENTRYFLD t2 ON t1."key" = t2."key"
  JOIN ENTRYFLD t3 ON t1."key" = t3."key"
 WHERE (t1."FIELDID"='24' AND t1."CONTENT"='w008760') 
   AND (t2."FIELDID"='25' AND t2."CONTENT"='COOKIE') 
   AND (t3."FIELDID"='26' AND t3."CONTENT"='rcTRI150003')
```

Or written without explicit joins:

```
SELECT t1."KEY"
  FROM ENTRYFLD t1, ENTRYFLD t2, ENTRYFLD t3 
 WHERE t1."key" = t2."key"
   AND t1."key" = t3."key"
   AND (t1."FIELDID"='24' AND t1."CONTENT"='w008760') 
   AND (t2."FIELDID"='25' AND t2."CONTENT"='COOKIE') 
   AND (t3."FIELDID"='26' AND t3."CONTENT"='rcTRI150003')
```

Or you could use a couple of correlated exists predicates (which might be the best option in any case):

```
SELECT t1."KEY"
FROM ENTRYFLD t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM ENTRYFLD t2 
    WHERE t1."KEY" = t2."KEY" AND (t2."FIELDID"='25' AND t2."CONTENT"='COOKIE')
    )
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM ENTRYFLD t3 
    WHERE t1."KEY" = t3."KEY" AND (t3."FIELDID"='26' AND t3."CONTENT"='rcTRI150003')
)
AND (t1."FIELDID"='24' AND t1."CONTENT"='w008760')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't use `Join`ing in the wrapper, and if you can use `EXISTS` in where clause, do this:

```
SELECT t.[KEY]
  FROM table_name t
 WHERE EXISTS (select * from  table_name  t1  where t1.[KEY] = t.[KEY] AND ( t1."FIELDID"='24' AND t1."CONTENT"='w008760')) 
   AND EXISTS (select * from  table_name  t2  where t2.[KEY] = t.[KEY] AND ( t2."FIELDID"='25' AND t2."CONTENT"='COOKIE'))
   AND EXISTS (select * from  table_name  t3  where t3.[KEY] = t.[KEY] AND ( t3."FIELDID"='26' AND t3."CONTENT"='rcTRI150003'))
```

Comment: You have to add t.key condition to the sub-queries, otherwise the whole table will be returned (or nothing at all...)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for keys that match on all three fields:

```
SELECT [KEY]
FROM [ENTRYFLD]
WHERE (([FIELDID]='24' AND [CONTENT]='w008760')
    OR ([FIELDID]='25' AND [CONTENT]='COOKIE')
    OR ([FIELDID]='26' AND [CONTENT]='rcTRI150003'))
GROUP BY [KEY]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Or, if you're using SQL Server you can `PIVOT` instead:

```
SELECT P.[KEY]
FROM (SELECT [KEY], [FIELDID], [CONTENT] FROM [ENTRYFLD]) A
PIVOT (MIN ([CONTENT]) FOR [FIELDID] IN ([24],[25],[26])) AS P
WHERE P.[24] = 'w008760'
AND P.[25] = 'COOKIE'
AND P.[26] = 'rcTRI150003'
```

Comment: Doesn't require all 3 different pairs, just 3 pairs - which may be the same pair 3 times. (See my answer for solution.)